# My while loop is unable to determine if the user input is valid when comparing two strings

Tags: c++

I have a program that is supposed to prompt the user to enter a valid choice if they insert the incorrect one, however now it recognizes every choice as an invalid choice. This takes place clearly within the while loop, and I was wondering if someone knew a fix. I know it likely has to do with me using ==, but I'm very new to c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "validateUserInput.h"
#include "calcTotalCharges.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char patientType = '\0';
    int numDays;
    double dailyRate, services, medication, total;

    cout << "This program will calculate a program's hospital charges." << endl;
    cout << "Enter I for in-patient or O for out-patient: ";
    cin >> patientType;

    while (patientType != 'I' || patientType != 'O')
    {
        cout << "Not a valid input." << endl;
        cout << "Enter I for in-patient or O for out-patient: ";
        cin >> patientType;
    }
```

Comment: You want an AND in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Lets translate your loop in to English:

While `patientType` is not 'I' **or** `patientType` is not 'O', do the thing.

Now, if `patientType` is 'I', it is not 'O', so the loop can continue.
And vice versa - if it is 'O', it is certainly not 'I', and again the loop can continue.

But what you want is to check that `patientType` is not 'I' **and** also not 'O' at the same time, meaning it is something else.

And you do that with `&&` which means logical AND in C++.
(You will learn about logical vs bitwise later)

So:

```
while (patientType != 'I' && patientType != 'O')
```

Comment: I actually feel really stupid for this one. Much appreciated.

Comment: @YungSlinger don't feel bad - this is actually a pretty common mistake for beginners, you try to check for several options at once without quite grasping the structure of the condition. You will get used to these operators as you continue learning. Good luck!